# Is there a way to close and reopen browser when using cucumber scenario outlines and webdriver io

Tags: cucumber, webdriver-io

I'm using v5 of web driver io and a cucumber framework. I have scenario outlines with multiple examples. I would like to close the browser and reopen it in between the examples so I have a clean webpage. But I can't find a way to do this. I'm sure I've seen anything about this but I can't find it.

I've looked through the webdriverio docs and the last things I can find was from 2016 which said it wasn't possible but there was a discussion about implementing something but I can't find any more detail.

Comment: if you want to open & close the browser for each scenario, then you should try to use '@Before' and '@After' hooks from cucumber. see docs here - https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this:

`browser.reloadSession()`

https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/reloadSession.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use hooks, I share an example below.

**UiHooks.java :**

```
import cucumber.api.Scenario;
import cucumber.api.java.After;
import cucumber.api.java.Before;

public class UiHooks {

public static final String BASE_URL = "https://baseURL/";
private Scenario scenario;

@Before
public void beforeScenario(Scenario scenario) {
    this.scenario = scenario;
        }

@After(order = 1)  //This will run first
public void afterScenario() {
    if (scenario.isFailed()){
       //do something like Secreen Shot or logger
        }
}

@After(order = 0)//This will run second
public void afterTest() {
   if (HookUtil.driver != null) {
        HookUtil.driver.close();
    }
    if (HookUtil.seleniumBase != null) {
        HookUtil.seleniumBase.stopService();
    }
}
}
```

**HookUtil.java :**

```
public class HookUtil {
public static WebDriver driver = null;
public static SeleniumBase seleniumBase = null;
}
```

**And then you can create a setup and call in the first step :**

```
private void Setup() {

    seleniumBase = new SeleniumBase(UiHooks.BASE_URL);
    driver = seleniumBase.getDriver();
    HookUtil.driver = driver;
    HookUtil.seleniumBase = seleniumBase;
}
```

Comment: Thank youfor the help I'll try them out